# When I try to filter data with a dropdown it does not update correctly

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks, dropdown

[image]
The function that filters is called handleFilter

Here I leave another image of the drop-down options

[image]

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you trim the screenshot to the code that needs to be looked at to understand the problem.

Comment: Please edit the post to include a [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with and have an issue using.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

u dont need to return useState setter, also u can use function state updater like this,

```
setTask(currentValue => currentValue.filter((item) => item.priority === 'basico'))
```